# Show branch key/name RecyclerView + Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I have been trying to show all my branches (Firebase) with RecyclerView on Android.
This is my JSON:

```
"notice" : {
    "notice1" : {
      "subnotice1" : "test1",
      "subnotice2" : "test2",
      "subnotice3" : {
        "test" : "test"
      }
    },
    "notice2" : {
      "subnotice1" : "test3",
      "subnotice2" : "test4"
    },
    "notice3" : {
      "subnotice1" : "test5",
      "subnotice2" : "test6"
    }
  }
}
```

I want to show with RecyclerView notice1, notice2, notice3 but it seems impossible to achieve.

What can I do?

Thanks in advance

Edit:

```
private List<String> lista = new ArrayList<>();
private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adaptador;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(recyclerView);
    rv.setHasFixedSize(false);
    rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    DatabaseReference dbr = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("compuestos");
    dbr.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            lista.removeAll(lista);
            for (DataSnapshot a : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                Log.d("DIEGO", a.getKey());
                lista.add(a.getKey());
            }
           for(String s: lista){
                Log.d("KOKO", s);
            }
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e("DIEGO", "ERROR", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });

    adaptador = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Datos, Holder>(Datos.class, R.layout.lista_elementos, Holder.class, dbr) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(Holder h, Datos d, int position) {               for(String s : lista){
                d.setCampo(s);
                h.setCampo(d.getCampo());
            }

        }
    };
    rv.setAdapter(adaptador);
}
```

Comment: Why it is impossible ? Say the reason

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: I don't know how to implement that with RecyclerView, It seems RecyclerView can only show "final branches" which contains finals variables as "subnotice1" : "testX", but doesn't show keys from branches

Comment: I have the Adapter, ViewHolder, etc... But as I said, only show finals Strings

Comment: Show your code what u have tried

Comment: Done @Piyush, that's my code

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**
I realized I had to keep the keys on ArrayList, and later just have to show it:

```
private ArrayList<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>();
//...

 ChildEventListener childEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            keys.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }
```

In Adapter:

```
mAdapter =
            new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Trabajo, TrabajoHolder>(Trabajo.class,R.layout.lista_trabajos ,TrabajoHolder.class, dbAvisos) {
                @Override
                protected void populateViewHolder(TrabajoHolder viewHolder, Trabajo model, int position) {
                        viewHolder.setKey(keys.get(position));
                }
            };
```

By this way "populateViewHolder" will show through RecyclerView all the keys we have at the Array.

I hope be useful.